# plain xetex page labels

Tags: xetex, pdf, page-numbering, plain-tex

there are some PDF files that some reader displays the printed page number as the current page number.
I also saw, that this can be achieved in latex with hyperref package.
what I'm look for is what`\special` command I need to achieve the same result; I can't find it in the PDF reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The page labels are set in the `/Catalog` object:

```
\special{pdf:docview <</PageLabels<< ... >>>>}
```

Example: `title`, `i`, `ii`, `1`, `2`

```
\special{pdf:docview <</PageLabels<</Nums[0<</P(title)>>1<</S/r>>3<</S/D>>]>>>>}
```

In the [PDF reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) it can be found in section **12.4.2 Page Labels** on [page 374 (382 of 756)](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=382).

Comment: As if I recall that I once saw this.

Comment: The good feature about this is that it can be issued anywhere in the document, so I can make a macro, that collect all the page numbering formats, and then puts this special command at the end of the document. (I'm not sure that it is good practice though.)

Comment: `\special` cannot be output _after_ the last page.

Comment: I didn't said that. But it can be put at the end of the last page.

Comment: But it can't be set in `\AtEndDocument`, because the last page might already be output.