# Plain TeX pdf2ps page numbering offset for front matter in PDF viewer

Tags: page-numbering, plain-tex, viewers, ps2pdf

The good:
When I use plain TeX, and then run `dvips` to get the Postscript output, I see negative page numbers for the front matter in the thumbnail pages on the left in `evince` and `gv` (ghostview), followed by positive page numbers starting at 1 after the front matter, although `okular` shows positive pages pages starting at 1 for the front matter, ignoring the negative page numbers of the front matter.

The bad:
When I convert the Postscript file to PDF using `ps2pdf`, all of my four PDF viewers show me the pages starting at 1 for the first physical page instead of using negative page numbers for the front matter. Then the numbering continues with a constant offset between the page number in the PDF thumbnails and the printed page number on each page.

What I would like is for the postscript-to-PDF conversion to produce a PDF file which shows pages -1 to -22 for the 22 pages of front matter, and then shows 1 for first page after the front matter. In other words, the thumbnails should show the page number which is printed on each page.

I've looked through the parameters for `ps2pdf` and `dvips`, but nothing there looks promising. I have heard that LaTeX users do get the right result, but I am using plain TeX.

---

PS. Here's a sample file which demonstrates the problem.

```
% test1.tex   2015-8-4   Alan U. Kennington.
% Demo of using \pageno to set negative page numbers, like normal plain TeX.
% Compile with tex, dvips and ps2pdf.

\pageno-1
Page minus 1.
\vfill\eject
Page minus 2.
\vfill\eject

\pageno1
Page plus 1.
\vfill\eject
Page plus 2.
\bye
```

The PDF viewers show pages i and ii as 1 and 2. Then they show pages 1 and 2 as 3 and 4. I would really like them to show i and ii as -1 and -2. Then they should show pages 1 and 2 as 1 and 2.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide us with a minimal working Plain TeXample ;-)

Comment: @AlanU.Kennington: So you are expecting from the people here to write an usual plain tex document to test the issue?

Comment: @AlanU.Kennington: I don't see the issue as I don't have a document to test the issue.

Comment: In latex hyperref takes care to store the page numbers by putting the necessary specials in the dvi. As far as I can see it puts `/PageLabels<</Nums[\HyPL@Labels]>>` in the pdf catalog.

Comment: @AlanU.Kennington OK, on that basis I've marked as such.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here: [plain xetex page labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74149/plain-xetex-page-labels/74162).
And here's a minimal example in plain TeX.
(It's minimal if you ignore the fish.)

```
\pageno-1
Page minus 1.
\vfill\eject
Page minus 2.
\vfill\eject

\special{pdf: docview << /PageLabels << /Nums[0 <</S /r>> 2 <</S /D>>] >> >> }
\special{pdf: docinfo << /Author (Fred Fish) /Title (Fried Fish) >> }

\pageno1
Page plus 1.
\vfill\eject
Page plus 2.
\bye
```

If this is compiled with `tex` and `dvipdfm`, the resulting PDF file shows the page numbers "i" and "ii" for the first two pages, and "1" and "2" for the 3rd and 4th pages in `evince`, `acroread` and `gv` PDF viewers, although my copy of `okular` just shows pages 1 to 4.

Anyway, this shows that the required parameters are getting into the PDF file from plain TeX. Definitely `dvips` does not accept these `\special` commands.

Many thanks to Heiko Oberdiek for posting the answer on 2012-09-26.
And for posting the crucial link:
http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf.

---

PS. 2015-8-5.
The 2013-8-13 answer by Heiko Oberdiek is comprehensive and detailed, much better than mine: [How can I achieve having logical page numbers shown in acrobat reader?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127990/how-can-i-achieve-having-logical-page-numbers-shown-in-acrobat-reader) There it is shown how to use `dvips` with a raw postscript `\special` instead of `dvipdfm` with the PDF `\special`. I have verified that the raw postscript method works as advertised for plain TeX with `dvips` and `ps2pdf`.